# Removing the (0) from the product reviews tab menu item in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I just added this code in child function php and it working to remove zero number from reviews but it shows error when the review is not enable in any product. 
How do I fix that?

```
// remove zero reviews
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'wp_woo_rename_reviews_tab', 98);
function wp_woo_rename_reviews_tab($tabs) {
    global $product;
    $check_product_review_count = $product->get_review_count();
    if ( $check_product_review_count == 0 ) {
        $tabs['reviews']['title'] = 'Reviews';
    } else {
        $tabs['reviews']['title'] = 'Reviews('.$check_product_review_count.')';
    }
    return $tabs;
}
```

Error:

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: What's your line 51 ?

Comment: here it is... 

https://ibb.co/drODOL

<?php call_user_func( $tab['callback'], $key, $tab ); ?>